# Why does this batch file close immediately when called from a shortcut, despite it working correctly when called from command line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

**Edit 3 (SOLUTION):**

As [michael_heath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9012170/michael-heath) described in his answer, the issue came down to two things: how exactly windows builds commands when executing something through a shortcut, and the very specific (and frankly ridiculous) consequences of the `\C` switch on `cmd.exe`. For future reference, if any other poor soul stumbles into this StackOverflow question, the problem was fixed by changing the "Target" property in the shortcut to a slightly edited version of Michael's answer, specifically `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C @"C:\{path-to-script}\link.bat"`. [Here's a screenshot too,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0n96V.png) if necessary, although you unfortunately can't see the whole Target line.

Huge thanks again to Michael.

---

I am attempting to make a personal batch utility to create a symlink on the desktop, much in the same way "Send to... > Desktop" works with shortcuts. I use symbolic links frequently to allow things like my bash configuration files (.bashrc and .bash_profile, etc) to be version controlled elsewhere for portability, and for several other things on my computer.

For ease of use, my idea was to create a simple batch file to do this for me, and place the symlink on the desktop. Then, I would put a shortcut to this file in the Send To folder so it appears in Send To in the context menu (I am aware that mklink requires admin privileges, so the shortcut is set to run as administrator also).

The following is the file I have written:

```
@echo off

set f=%~1
set switch=
if exist "%f%\*" set switch=/D

for /F "delims=" %%i in ("%f%") do set name=%%~nxi

mklink %switch% "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%name%" "%f%"
if not %ERRORLEVEL%==0 pause
```

Here is the general idea of what I'm trying to do:

1. Strip the quotes on the input, if any (%~1)
2. Check if the input is a directory
3. Get the base name and file extension of the input (%%~nxi)
4. Make the link
5. If an error occurred, pause so it can be seen rather than exiting (because the batch file is called from the shortcut)

It works perfectly fine until I give it an input that contains spaces in the name of the file or directory. I actually haven't tested what happens if there is a directory with a space in the path, but not in the base name of the actual file or directory, but I assume the same problem will be present.

I have made several changes to attempt to get it to work with files with spaces, including stripping the quotes on the input in that first line so that the quotes aren't doubled later, and that "delims=" thing on the for loop. Those two solutions I found here, actually.

But despite my best efforts, no matter what I do, the file closes immediately when given an input with a space. I have littered every line with `pause`s, run the script from the command line with a manually entered input so it would not exit, and run each individual command (where possible) from the command line.

Infuriatingly, when I run it from the command line or run the individual commands, it all works perfectly even with spaces in the input. I even created another batch file that does nothing but output the input it receives and ran *that* from Send To, and confirmed that the input is the same as I entered from the command line.

What on Earth is going wrong then when called from that shortcut in Send To?

---

**Edit 1:** The properties of the shortcut itself are as follows:

- Target: C:\Users{username}\vc\git\util-scripts\bat\link.bat
- Start in: C:\Users{username}\vc\git\util-scripts\bat

Here is a screenshot as well:

[Because I just made my account here I can't embed the picture but here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erfcP.png)

---

**Edit 2:** This is the current code I am using, as suggested by Gerhard Barnard, however the problem still persists:

```
@echo off

set "fname=%~1"
set switch=
if exist "%fname%\.*" set "switch=/D"

for /F "delims=" %%i in ("%fname%") do (
    mklink %switch% "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%%~nxi" "%fname%"
    if errorlevel 1 pause
)
```

Comment: So you are saying you are dragging multiple files to the batch file and that is where the problem comes in?

Comment: @gerhard-barnard No, just one file. I'm right clicking on the file and selecting the batch file from Send To. For the sake of being explicit, it's a directory that contains a space.

Comment: If it works fine from console, then it might be the command in the shortcut that is the issue. [edit] the question to add the shortcut command if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Set the path for the created symlink.
set "linkdir=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"

for %%A in (%*) do call :link "%%~A"

rem Check results.
echo: & dir /A:L "%linkdir%" & pause
exit /b

:link
set "switch="
if exist "%~1\*" set "switch=/D"
for /F "delims=" %%A in ("%~1") do set "name=%%~nxA"
if not defined name echo Variable "name" not defined.& exit /b 1
mklink %switch% "%linkdir%\%name%" "%~1"
exit /b 0
```

Your batch-file code is working.
This code does multiple file or folders.
This code also helped to test all at once,
files, folders, symlinked files and symlinked
folders as targets.

If you only want 1 target to be processed,
then just change the `%*` to `"%~1"`.

The main issue is the command string in the shortcut.

```
C:\Users\{username}\vc\git\util-scripts\bat\link.bat
```

The file type of `.bat` is going to build a command such as:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Users\{username}\vc\git\util-scripts\bat\link.bat" %*
```

`%*` is substituted with the passed arguments.

If you have the command with an argument with double quotes,
it may look like:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Users\{username}\vc\git\util-scripts\bat\link.bat" "C:\Users\a file.txt"
```

The command string after `/C` has 4 double quotes
and double quotes are at both ends.
The behavior changes due to the double quotes.

A quote from `cmd /?`:

> ```
> If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
> the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
> used to process quote (") characters:
>
>     1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
>         on the command line are preserved:
>
>         - no /S switch
>         - exactly two quote characters
>         - no special characters between the two quote characters,
>           where special is one of: &<>()@^|
>         - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
>           two quote characters
>         - the string between the two quote characters is the name
>           of an executable file.
>
>     2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
>         a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
>         remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
>         any text after the last quote character.
> ```

In section 1, *"no /S switch"* is true, then the next is
*"exactly two quote characters"* which is false.
This now applies section 2, which can make the
command string after `/C` with stripped double quotes:

```
C:\Users\{username}\vc\git\util-scripts\bat\link.bat" "C:\Users\a file.txt
```

The space is quoted though the rest is exposed,
which is an invalid command string in this case.
Note that `C:\Users\a file.txt` is an example
passed argument that was double quoted as
`"C:\Users\a file.txt"`.

A change in the command string in the shortcut to:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C echo: & "C:\Users\{username}\vc\git\util-scripts\bat\link.cmd"
```

The command is now `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` which
gives some more control with the command string.
After the `/C`, `echo:` is used to avoid the command
string beginning with a double quote, which helps to
prevent double quotes being stripped at both ends because
the command string no longer starts with a double quote.
After the `&` is the command that is important and will
now work even if the arguments end with a double quote.

You can replace the `echo: &` with another initial command.
You can also use `@` before the command string, so the shortcut
command string would be:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C @"C:\Users\{username}\vc\git\util-scripts\bat\link.cmd"
```

So whatever works the best for your use case.

Comment: This is an absolute miracle, thank you so much. After reading the previous messages here I knew it would come down to some extremely cryptic consequence of how exactly windows shortcuts build commands, and thank god someone who knows that information saw this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try without the `/F` option which is not needed here, we also do not need to set a variable as it will work perfectly fine with the expanded meta variable:

```
@echo off
set "fname=%~1"
set switch=
if exist "%fname%\.*" set "switch=/D"

for %%i in ("%fname%") do (
    echo mklink %switch% "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%%~nxi" "%fname%"
    if errorlevel 1 pause
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not only does this not fix the problem, but now it no longer pauses on error. `errorlevel 0` does not seem to be a command on my machine, but even when I returned it to `if not %ERRORLEVEL%==0 pause` it still would not pause on error (which I tested by linking a file twice, creating a naming conflict).

Actually, after returning it to what it was in the question and removing the "/F" option, it did not work at all, on files or folders, whether they had spaces in the name or not. It did however work when I copied yours verbatim (except for the pause on error as I said before).

Comment: Also, I am aware I don't need to set the variable but I just find it easier to work with if I store manipulated variables in other variables for future use :)

Comment: No, it still isn't working for paths with spaces, sadly.